# How to implement variables in the this.state.shown ? "constant " : " constant"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to show the text box value in this.state.shown but i accepts only constants if give variable name it prints the same. how to use variable here for eg:

```
{this.state.shown ? "Reject Reason" : "Accepted Reason"}
```

is working fine.

```
<textarea placeholder="Reason for Rejection" id="mdlplc" className="mdlcnt"/>

const rejectReason = document.getElementsByClassName("mdlcnt").innerHTML;

{this.state.shown ? "rejectReason " : ""}
```

its not working?

---

My full component code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-responsive-modal';
import '../dashboard/Dashboard.css';
import './BasicTable.css';
//import SearchField from 'react-search-field';

export class BasicTable extends Component {

  state = {
    open: false,
  };
  onSubmitdata = () => {
    this.setState({open: false});
    this.setState({ shown: !this.state.shown });
  }
  onOpenModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: true });
  };
  on
  onCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;
    const rejectReason = document.getElementsByClassName("mdlcnt").innerHTML;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">  

        <h4 className="card-title"> View Appointments</h4>

          <div className="col-lg-12 grid-margin stretch-card">
            <div className="card">
              <div className="card-body">
              <div className="table-responsive">
                  <table className="table reposive" >

                   <tr >
                       <td className="noBorder" id="details">Doctor Name</td> 
                       <td className="noBorder"> Jessica Smith</td>
                   </tr>  
                   <tr>
                       <td className="noBorder" id="details">Patient Name</td> 
                       <td className="noBorder">Jack Robinson</td>
                   </tr>  
                   <tr>
                       <td className="noBorder" id="details">Date</td> 
                       <td className="noBorder">Jan 15 2020</td>
                   </tr>  
                   <tr>
                       <td className="noBorder" id="details">Time</td> 
                       <td className="noBorder"> 9.00 AM to 9.00 AM</td>
                   </tr>  
                   <tr>
                       <td className="noBorder" id="details">Status</td> 
                       <td className="noBorder" id="status">BOOKED</td>
                   </tr>  
                   <tr>
                       <td className="noBorder" id="details"> {this.state.shown ? "Reject Reason" : ""}</td> 
                       <td className="noBorder" >{this.state.shown ? rejectReason : ""}</td>
                   </tr> 
                  </table>
                  <button onClick={this.onOpenModal} className="badge badge-dange">Reject Appointment</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>

        <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal} center>
          <p id="mdlhd">Reject Appointment</p>
          <textarea  placeholder="Reason for Rejection" id="mdlplc" className="mdlcnt" />
          <button id="mdlsbt" onClick={this.onSubmitdata}>Submit</button>
          <button id="mdlcnl" onClick={this.onCloseModal}>Cancel</button>
        </Modal>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default BasicTable
```

Comment: Is there only 1 element with the class ame mdlcnt? If no, you are holding an array..

Comment: Yes there is only one element with this name

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `ref` to the element to have a reference to the element itself and you can get the `value` of it:

```
constructor(props){ // add this block to your class component.
    super(props);
    this.mdlplcRef = React.createRef() // in a class component's constructor
}
// const mdlplcRef = useRef(); // the functional component way
```

then use this ref to the element:

```
<textarea ref={this.mdlplcRef} 
          placeholder="Reason for Rejection" 
          id="mdlplc" className="mdlcnt"/>
```

Now in the render update this line to get the value:

```
// const rejectReason = document.getElementsByClassName("mdlcnt").innerHTML;
const rejectReason = this.mdlplcRef.current.value;

{this.state.shown ? rejectReason : ""}
```

Comment: where to use  this.mdlplcRef = React.createRef()

Comment: checkout the comments i gave after the line. The line can be put in the constructor if it is a class component.

Comment: can you add your component code in the question? It is hard to tell against your last comment.

Comment: @SabrilogeshK you have added the code in my answer. No, you have to put it in your question.

Comment: ReferenceError: Must call super constructor in derived class before accessing 'this' or returning from derived constructor

Comment: @SabrilogeshK ahh. yes you have to call super. edited again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207833/discussion-between-sabrilogesh-k-and-jai).